# Play Application's JVM Instance and Akka Actor System Handling

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I am new to Play Framework and evaluating it's features and capabilities.

As per my current knowledge, when deploying the Play Application we can deploy and run multiple instances of the same application on the same server box (e.g. a linux box having Java installed).

Now my question is, does each running instance of this same play application in the same server get it's own JVM instance and Akka actor system instance on which it runs on?

Or is it on top of the same JVM instance and Akka actor system instance all these play application instances of the same application running?

Thanks.

Comment: Each Play app uses one JVM instance. As the actor system is started by Play, I guess it uses the same JVM of the app that started it...